# Nginx + NextJS + NestJS + Postgres as Docker Compose accessable in LAN

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, wsl-2, lan

I decided to transfer all my projects to PC. I also have a macbook, but there is not enough space on it, and 8 GB of RAM is not enough to hold several Docker-Compose projects without noticeable lags.

But I love working on mac. Already set up a code-server, wsl2 with ubuntu 20.04.

I have a big problem with WSL2 and Docker and proxy in LAN to other device.

There is an application with four containers: NestJS+NextJS+NGinx+Postgres. Inside them there is a bridge network. Docker runs over WSL2 on my PC.

When I bring up the server, there is a connection on the localhost, but the proxies on the _next/ path in NGinx do not work.

From my macbook, there is no answer at all over the local network. Below is my yml file and nginx config:

in Windows:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=192.168.3.2 connectport=80 connectaddress=172.31.32.32

```
# Cache zone
# proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

# NextJS
# upstream frontend {
#   server frontend:3000;
# }

# NestJS
# upstream backend {
#   server backend:5000;
# }

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  
  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


  location /_next/static/ {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://frontend:3000/_next/static/;
  }

  # location /_next/webpack-hmr {
  #     proxy_pass http://frontend;
  # } 

  # Прокси на NestJS
  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://backend:5000/;
      # rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  }

  # Прокси на Nextjs
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
  }
}
```

```yaml
version: '3.9'

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  # PostreSQL
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    # command: bash -c "su - postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql  -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -c \"create database xxxxxxxxx;\"'"
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/pg
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxxxxxx
    expose:
      - '5432'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network

  # NestJS Backend
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./static:/app/static
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_HOST=xxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxxxx
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - database
    expose:
      - 5000
    networks:
      - app-network

  # NextJS Frontend
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./static:/app/public
    depends_on:
      - backend
    expose:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
    networks:
      - app-network
```

I've already tried everything I could find on the Internet.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve